# Looking for a way to manage iphone platform builds with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, makefile

I have an iPhone platform.  We currently have 14 apps in the app store that use the same code base with a few exceptions.

- plist file
- AppStyle.m
- Lot of image assets

I am looking for a better way to manage all these builds and still be able to run an individual build in the simulator.

If I was using Make I would run through a series of scripts to get the build directory set-up based on which app I was building.  And the particular app would just be a variable to the build.   As it stands now I am adding a Target for each new app and assigning assets and .m files via Xcode.

There must be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're familiar with make, then just use make to write your build scripts.

- Copy your plist, style tool, and assets to the appropriate locations in your project
- trigger the project to build using the command line tool `xcodebuild`.
- launch it in the simulator using something like `iphonesim`

http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/xcodebuild/

https://github.com/jhaynie/iphonesim

Another approach to doing this kind of thing is to put the shared code into a common library or framework, then prepare a project template that automatically includes the library and any other project prep.  When you need to start a new project, use that project template instead of the standard templates, and just edit the branded/styled bits as appropriate.

Comment: Awesome thanks.  So simple it will work for everything accept the provisioning profiles.  I'll have to figure out how to dynamically change that.